# Who joined when?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

An institute runs batches training students in C#. A new batch starts on the 1st of every month and every batch lasts for exactly 3 months (thus at any given time, the students of exactly 3 batches will be present concurrently). The table below gives the information for the total number of students studying at the institute in each month of 2018 (some values have intentionally been left blank).

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total Students | 283 | 284 | 286 | 284 | 282 | 284 |  | 283 | 276 | 273 | 278 | 279 |

It is also known that 95 new students joined in May, while 91 new students joined in September.

How many joined when and how many left when? Please share your approach.

Source : IMS https://www.imsindia.com/

Comment: Where does this puzzle come from?

Comment: "IMS" could stand for almost anything, and nothing I see in my first page of search results makes it obvious what it is. Could you please be a lot more specific? If the thing is on the internet, make a link; if it's from a printed thing, say what. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link to imsindia.com -- but this is still extremely vague. Is this from some sort of ongoing competition? Are you copying things from their printed materials, or from their website, or what? ... And do you have their permission to reproduce their questions here?

Comment: In what possible sense are you not copying their material? It's right there in what you posted. Of course you're copying their material. I'm asking whether you have their permission to do it.

Comment: If there's no single solution and no definitive answer for some months like @gabbo1092 and Weather Vane noted in their answers/comments. What answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the starting point with `g` and `k` known.

> ```
>     Old  Cur  New 
> Jan  a +  b +  c = 283
> Feb  b +  c +  d = 284
> Mar  c +  d +  e = 286
> Apr  d +  e +  f = 284
> May  e +  f + 95 = 282
> Jun  f + 95 +  h = 284
> Jul 95 +  h +  i =  ?
> Aug  h +  i +  j = 283
> Sep  i +  j + 91 = 276
> Oct  j + 91 +  l = 273
> Nov 91 +  l +  m = 278
> Dec  l +  m +  n = 279
> ```
>
> By subtracting Sep from Aug we know `h = 98` so now we have
>
> ```
>  Jun  f + 95 + 98 = 284
> ```
>
> so we know know `f = 91` and this can be now worked back to Jan to give
>
> ```
>     Old  Cur  New 
> Jan 96 + 94 + 93 = 283
> Feb 94 + 93 + 97 = 284
> Mar 93 + 97 + 96 = 286
> Apr 97 + 96 + 91 = 284
> May 96 + 91 + 95 = 282
> Jun 91 + 95 + 98 = 284
> Jul 95 + 98 +  i =  ?
> Aug 98 +  i +  j = 283
> Sep  i +  j + 91 = 276
> Oct  j + 91 +  l = 273
> Nov 91 +  l +  m = 278
> Dec  l +  m +  n = 279
> ```
>
> One more can be found, by subtracting Nov from Dec we know `n = 92`
>
> ```
> Dec  l +  m + 92 = 279
> ```

But as far as I can see the rest can only be quess-work.

Comment: I think after this point, you can give an upper and lower limit on i (185 and 3 respectively, if my numbers are correct), and each of those lead to a different solution.

Comment: It is correct Weather Vane. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a solution:

> ```
>   |Total|New|Leaving
>  J| 283 | 93| 96 
>  F| 284 | 97| 94 
>  M| 286 | 96| 93 
>  A| 284 | 91| 97 
>  M| 282 | 95| 96 
>  J| 284 | 98| 91 
>  J| 289 | 96| 95 
>  A| 283 | 89| 98 
>  S| 276 | 91| 96 
>  O| 273 | 93| 89 
>  N| 278 | 94| 91 
>  D| 279 | 92| 93
> ```

General approach:

> I started by filling in the totals, number of students entered in May and September which lead to number of students leaving in July and November. I then started subbing in possible rough numbers based on the numbers known. Then I basically adjusted the numbers as necessary starting near the bottom where more was strictly defined and working my way up since Jan and Feb have more flexibility in adjusting without effecting the other numbers. After a few iterations eventually got to numbers that worked under all the restraints.

Comment: Your answer looks correct. Can you pls share your approach? Especially for Jan and April.

Comment: Sorry, But your answer is wrong. For some months, we cannot find the no of new joinees or left students.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you are saying is wrong with the answer. Are you saying the problem is defined in such a way that you cannot find one definitive solution?

Comment: Yes, for some months we cannot find definite soln